# How to change the order of x-axis labels in a seaborn lineplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have the following data frame:

```
df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted.head()

Task    Pulse Time  Pulse Measure
0   Language    PRE_RELAX_PULSE 90.0
1   Language    PRE_RELAX_PULSE 94.0
2   Language    PRE_RELAX_PULSE 52.0
3   Language    PRE_RELAX_PULSE 70.0
4   Language    PRE_RELAX_PULSE 84.0
```

When I attempt a barplot of this data, I get the following:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="Pulse Time", y="Pulse Measure", hue="Task", data=df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted)
```

[image]

However, when I try to use a line plot, I get the following:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Pulse Time", y="Pulse Measure", hue="Task", data=df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted)
```

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the order of the x-axis labels is in a different order from the barplot. Is it possible to change the order of the x-axis in the lineplot? I tried to use the "order" function within the sns.lineplot as follows:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Pulse Time", y="Pulse Measure", hue="Task", data=df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted, order='PRE_RELAX_PULSE','30S_RELAX_PULSE','POST_RELAX_PULSE')
```

However, that produces an error.

``AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'order'

Comment: Do you just need brackets around the order you specified to make it a list?

Comment: When I try this with brackets: ax = sns.lineplot(x="Pulse Time", y="Pulse Measure", hue="Task", data=df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted, order=['PRE_RELAX_PULSE','30S_RELAX_PULSE','POST_RELAX_PULSE']). It still gives me the following error: 'Line2D' object has no property 'order'

Comment: try adding `sort=False` to your lineplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the plot order of the categorical x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630875/how-to-change-the-plot-order-of-the-categorical-x-axis) (This is a later answer to a similar question, but it is a more general one.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sort=False` will do it.

As the [seaborn doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) states:

> **sort** : boolean, optional
>
> If True, the data will be sorted by the x and y variables, otherwise
>   lines will connect points in the order they appear in the dataset.

The x variables are sorted in their "string-order":

```
'30s_RELAX_PULSE' < 'POST_RELAX_PULSE' < 'PRE_RELAX_PULSE'
```

which is not wanted.

The wanted behaviour is the aggregation by the x-values. This is done with the `estimator='mean'` (default). Every "Pulse Measure"(y) is grouped by the "Pulse Time" (x) and then the mean is calculated.

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x="Pulse Time", y="Pulse Measure", hue="Task",sort= False, data=df1_Relax_Pulse_Melted)
```

My Plot with other sample data:

[image: correct order of the x variables]